# Adding a hop using `ip route add` makes traceroute stop at the first hop

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, traceroute

I am practising for LFCS. I have two virtual machines, ubuntu 18.04 both.
On machine1, when i run `traceroute 8.8.8.8` I have a normal output. When on machine1 I run

```
 sudo ip route add 8.8.0.0/16 proto static metric 10 via inet if-of-machine2 dev ens3
```

then the traceroute stops at the first hop as follows

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  machine2  0.439 ms  0.380 ms  0.359 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
.....
```

and never completes.
On machine2, `traceroute 8.8.8.8` is absolutely successful. Also I set

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I flushed `iptables` and i made sure all policies are set to ACCEPT. `ufw` is disabled.

What am i missing? Why is traceroute not going further my first hop on machine1?

Answer (score 0):

#### Troubleshooting

- Check the routes on the machine2 with command `ip route get 8.8.8.8 from <ip-machine1> iif <iface>`. It should return a valid route.
- Check outgoing packets with the `tcpdump`.
- Likely you need the `SNAT/MASQUERADE` rule, otherwise all next hops should know route to source.

Comment: $ ip route get 8.8.8.8 from machine1 iif ens3 outputs
8.8.8.8 from machine1 via 192.168.123.1 dev ens3 
    cache <redirect> iif ens3

Comment: tcpdump outputs
13:11:38.460907 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.52:54:00:d5:bb:17.8003, length 35

Comment: Hm.. It's a strange, because you have a redirect. Draw your topology.

Comment: What do you mean, _Draw your topology_? You mean network diagram? I am afraid this is a bit too advanced for my level of knowledge but I will try.